# Multiple port names required when only using one port

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service

I have one port specified as below.

my-app-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: my-port
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: my-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

cloudbuild.yaml summary:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy
```

For some reason I get an error asking for a name param on port1, when port1 doesn't even exist. See below.

output:

```
Step #3: Applying deployment.
Step #3: Getting access to cluster "my-cluster" in "my-zone".
Step #3: Configuration files to be used: [{kind: Deployment, name: my-app} {kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler, name: my-app-hpa} {kind: Service, name: my-app-service}]
Step #3: Applying configuration files to cluster.
Step #3: Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
Step #3: The Service "my-app-service" is invalid: 
Step #3: * spec.ports[1].name: Required value
```

Kubernetes version: 1.15.9-gke.24

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: can you specify which kubernetes version? also did you try to create using `kubectl create -f my-app-service.yaml`?

Comment: Version is 1.15.9-gke.24. When I run kubectl create I get: `service/my-app-service created`

Comment: `When I run kubectl create I get: service/my-app-service created` so when you get the error?

Comment: When building on google cloud. I've extended the build logs in my post

Comment: When I run kubectl apply on my-app-service.yaml I get the same error as in GC build (port name required value)

Comment: From which application does this output of `Step #3:...` comes from? I used your service definition and it works without any problems. Could you try to delete everything this application did and try to run this definitions without it? This could point where the issue lies.

Comment: The output is from Cloud Build. I've added a summary of cloudbuild.yaml to the post. @DawidKruk

Comment: I just had the same thing doing a KodeKloud exercise. It seems to be a bugged error message that simply means you can't replace a running service with the apply command. Using the replace command worked, which presumably means one could also delete the service before the apply, and it will also work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recreating the yaml worked:

```
kubectl delete -f service.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
```

Comment: Good to hear. yaml is definitely finicky. Glad you got things working.

Comment: A shorter version: `kubectl replace --force -f service.yaml`.

Comment: that did it for me! phew

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yaml alignment issue. Make sure the array of ports is indented under "ports"

Try:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: my-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Indentation doesn't seem to make a difference. I've tried what you specified (also updated the post accordingly).

Comment: @willy-g try putting name first. I'll update my answer.